# curl login script to a javascript page

Tags: curl

Hy all.

I try to use curl script to login a page with a javascript submit process with out any luck...

Can someone help me ?

Here is the form :

```
<li class="login_title_right"></li>
</ul>
<div class="content login_content">
<ul class="login_blank"></ul>
<ul class="login_ul_1">
<li class="login_li_1"><span>Username</span></li>
<li class="login_li_2">
<input type="text" class="username" name="Username" id="Frm_Username">
</li>
</ul>
<ul class="login_blank"></ul>
<ul class="login_ul_1">
<li class="login_li_1"><span>Password</span></li>
<li class="login_li_2">
<input type="password" class="password" name="Password"  id="Frm_Password">

</li>
<li class="login_li_3">
<input class="login" type="submit"  id="LoginId"  value="Login"  onclick="dosubmit()">
</li>
</ul>
```

Transform that plz in a curls login script . The username to login is "admin" and password is "xxx123"

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
curl -b cookies.txt -c cookies.txt --data "Username=admin&Password=xxx123&Login=Login" [urlthatyour form sumbits]
```

You need cookies if you want to make another curl request after logging in. the session id in cookies will help next curl request authorized.

If you don't want cookies you can use

```
curl --data "Username=admin&Password=xxx123&Login=Login" [url that your form submits]
```

typically form action will be your url.

Try to add name to your submit button. I used id for login here. Never tried, not sure if it works but name should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use it directly on the page. You would need to find out what page the script requests to (or the `action` value of the form).

As you haven't provided the `form` tags or the script's contents, we can't help.

Comment: <form name="fLogin" id="fLogin" method="post"  onsubmit="return false;" action="">
<input type="hidden" name="_lang" id="_lang" value="" disabled>
<input type="hidden" name="frashnum" id="frashnum" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="Frm_Logintoken" id="Frm_Logintoken" value="">
<div class="login_bg">