# Passing credentials to the links browser on the CLI

Tags: bash, shell, browser, credentials

I am using the `links` webbrowser in one of my scripts. The web page will ask for a username and a password. The problem is that I have to provide the credentials on each visit manually.

Is there any way to pass credentials to `links` on the command line interface?

Currently my code looks like this:

```
total="http://10.239.107.1/rt/Search/Results.tsv"
links $total
```

Comment: It is complicated to guess where and what is the problem if you don't provide some code.

Comment: Do you talk about something like a password manager which will automatically fill in/provide the needed credentials?

Comment: yes..something like that only..
will it be possible in links command or any other command ??

Comment: Not with `links` as far as I know. Just have a look if this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5885815/curl-login-script-to-a-javascript-page - and that: https://superuser.com/questions/640839/how-to-enter-login-information-for-a-website-from-the-linux-command-line